# Next.js with prettier formatting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, formatter, prettier

I'm trying to format my next.js project with prettier. In my package.json I've defined this:

```
"scripts": {
"format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js, jsx}\"",
},
```

So my project has a lot of folders:

- components
- layouts
- pages
- .next

I obviously don't want to run prettier in my `.next` folder. How can I ignore some folders?

Comment: You can try creating `.prettierignore` folder and then add `.next` in there

Comment: `prettier --write .` did the trick for me (matching include/ignore config)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
"scripts": {
"format": "prettier --write \"{,!(.next)/**/}*.{js, jsx}\"",
},
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a good .prettierignore setup for a base Next.js install on the official github. I use this one a lot as a base to start from.

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/.prettierignore

```
node_modules
**/.next/**
**/_next/**
**/dist/**
**/__tmp__/**
lerna.json
.github
```

Comment: This is a great starting point - but a bit too much as you don't need to ignore the `packages/next` as that is specific to the next repo

Answer (score 3):

You can add ***.prettierignore*** in the project root directory.

```
node_modules
.next
out
```

It uses [.gitignore syntax](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format).